# Connecting shielding vias

Tags: pcb-design, rf

Do I need to connect the vias of a shield to a net(the ground layer)? Or do just through-hole vias act as a shield? I have stitching as well that obviously connects to the ground layer but I wasn't sure about shielding.

[image]

Comment: Yes the shielding cannot be left floating. How you do it also matters. Just a single point connection won't work. Think about it this way: the stitching is just as much as part of the shield as the metal cap is.

Comment: what do you mean by a single point? If I connect the shielding vias to my ground plane is that enough?

Comment: You are asking about a metal can that sits on the PCB, yes?

Comment: No, shielding as in via shielding RF traces. Basically placing vias along RF traces so as to protect the trace from noise and other board interference. But I do believe that you answered my question as vias not connected to my ground plane would be floating copper and could cause noise.

Comment: "*Do I need to connect the vias of a shield*" What do you mean by "shield" in this sentence? Are you talking about a shield made of vias? Because it reads like a shield component that contains vias. I suppose it doesn't matter: The parts of shield cannot be left floating and must be connected to ground with as low *impedance* = continuous connection to ground rather than single point.

Comment: im referring to the network of vias that surround the trace, i've updated the question to include a picture

Comment: Oh, so a shield made of vias. Or a via fence. That is supposed to act like a can and you know that a can can't be left floating. Better if you have a ground plane above and below that too for full enclosure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the surfaces of a shield cannot be left floating and must be connected to ground with as much of a geometrically continuous connection as possible for lowest impedance.